Error details: insufficient access rights on object id
I am facing insufficient access rights on object id while delete document from custom and corresponding contentDocument.
@AuraEnabled(cacheable=false)
    public static void deleteFileRecord(String documentId)  //documentId from js 
{       
        try {
            List<MSFiles__c> getMSFiles = [SELECT Id, MSFiles_Url__c, ContentDocumentId__c, Comments__c 
                                              FROM MSFiles__c 
                                              WHERE ContentDocumentId__c =: documentId];            
            ContentDocument contentDocument = [SELECT Id, Title FROM ContentDocument WHERE Id =: documentId];            
            if (contentDocument != null) {               
                delete getMSFiles;               
                delete contentDocument;
            } else {
                throw new CustomException('No file record found for the given documentId');
            }
        } catch (System.DmlException e) {
            System.debug('Error deleting file record: ' + e.getMessage());
            System.debug('Error details: ' + e.getDmlMessage(0));
            throw new AuraHandledException('An error occurred while deleting the file record');
        }
}

Error I am getting:

|USER_DEBUG|[110]|DEBUG|Error details: insufficient access rights on object id.

Org - Wide settings for MSFiles__c is set to Public Read/Write.

In general "Public Read/Write" does not grant the right to delete. Apart from that - is accessing the ID of the custom object or of the Content Document that is failing?

e to SFSE.  Please take a moment to read [ask] and take the [tour]. Please [edit] your post to clarify which delete is throwing the error.  Is the MSFiles or the contentDocument?  Please [edit] your post to include this information.

You are getting this error not because you don't have access to the object but because you don't have access to the record that you are trying to delete.
There are a couple of solutions to this:

Run your code without sharing
Give view all, and modify all permissions to the user.
Make the running user the owner of the record(manually or programmatically) and then delete the record.

